# Oracle APEX page item set in an ajax callback does not persist

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have the following code in my ajax callback (PL/SQL):

```
:P1_CNT := TO_NUMBER(:P1_CNT) + 1;
apex_util.set_session_state
     (p_name  => 'P1_CNT'
     ,p_value => :P1_CNT
     );
```

Which seems to work just fine. But then a process is called that checks that page item and page item comes up as 0 even though in the callback it is set to 1. How can I fix that?

The code that calls the ajax is javascript below, executed from a custom dynamic action:

```
for ( var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
        apex.server.process
            ("my_ajax_callback"
            ,{x01:records[i][1]}
            ,{type:'GET', dataType: 'text', success: function( text) {}}
            );
}


apex.page.submit( 'COMPLETE_PROCESS_RECORDS' );
```

Where COMPLETE_PROCESS_RECORDS is the process that executes once all the records in the loop have been processed by ajax callback. the ajax callback evaluates each record passed to it and processes some and discards others. P1_CNT is incremented every time a record was processed further.

Comment: The call to `apex_util.set_session_state` is not needed. When executing PL/SQL, APEX will first identify the bind variables and set them from session state before executing the code. Then, after execution, it will see if any of the values have changed and if so, map them back to persisted session state automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us the code that calls the Ajax callback, but basically, there's server-side (PL/SQL in this case) and client-side (JavaScript) code. For the server to get values from the client-side, you have to send them in when calling the Ajax callback. That's what the `pData` parameter is for:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aexjs/apex.server.html#.process

You can access the values you send to the server-side code in different ways depending on how you send them in. For example, if you send in a value with `x01`, you can refer to it in your PL/SQL code with `apex_application.g_x01`.

Of course, sometimes you need to get values from the server-side to the client-side. For this, typically you'd send an HTTP response from your PL/SQL code. Here's an example that sends a JSON object:

```
apex_json.open_object();
apex_json.write('hello', 'world');
apex_json.close_object();
```

You would then need to update your client-side code to look at and use the HTTP response to map the values to whatever part of the page/DOM you need.

This is so typical that the APEX team made it very simple if you're using the Dynamic Action framework instead of raw JavaScript. There's an action named Execute PL/SQL that has attributes named **Items to Submit** and **Items to Return** that can do the heavy lifting for you.

[image: Execute PL/SQL]

Comment: the ajax is called from a javascript from a custom dynamic action. I added the code to the question

Comment: There are a couple of issues with the code you've displayed. 1) You're in a loop making calls to `apex.server.process`. This is bad because you're potentially making lots of unnecessary round trips to the database when you could make just one call instead. 2) While the loop is synchronous, the calls to `apex.server.process` are not, so you'll end up submitting the page before all the calls to `apex.server.process` have finished. If there are any errors, you'll never know about them. Normally, you'd want to call `apex.page.submit` in the `success` callback of the Ajax call (if there was one)

Comment: I can't really call submit the page as not all the records have been processed. What alternatives do I have?

Comment: I need a better sense of what you're trying to do before I can help. This question started about "page item set in an ajax callback does not persist", but clearly we're going in a different direction here. Please describe what this page is showing, what you're processing with the JavaScript, why you need to map values back to the page from the Ajax process, why you need to submit the page, etc. When I better understand what you're trying to do I can offer suggestions on how to best do it.